# Adding urldecode to getURL array

Tags: url, geturl

I need to add urldecode to the below function but unsure how to modify it so...

```
public function getAddFilterUrl($attribute)
{
    $filtering = $this->getRequest()->getParam('filtering', array());
    $filtering[] = $attribute->getAttributeCode();

    return $this->getUrl('*/*/*', array(
        '_current' => true,
        '_escape' => true,
        '_query' => array(
            'filtering' => array_unique($filtering)
        )
    ));
}
```

For example, the current URL outputted from the above is:-

```
/price_update/products/key/3b6f41cb95705740b8f46bbf1411a5e1/?filtering%5B0%5D=manufacturer
```

And what I want to output is:-

```
/price_update/products/key/3b6f41cb95705740b8f46bbf1411a5e1/?filtering[0]=manufacturer
```

I have tried modifying `_escape` in the `array` to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely you could

```
return urldecode($this->getUrl('*/*/*', array(
    '_current' => true,
    '_escape'  => true,
    '_query' => array(
        'filtering' => array_unique($filtering)
    )
)));
```

Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, not missing anything `urldecode` worked perfectly as per your answer. Thanks.